# Why is this an error with this UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql

I keep getting the error 'Could not update data: Query was empty'

It must be syntax but I have just about tried everything.

```
mysql_query("UPDATE mytable SET field1 = 1 WHERE ID = 1");
```

I've been up since 4am and can't find a solution which must be staring me in the face.

```
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password");
mysql_select_db("$db_name");
```

I have a Session and i dont think I need to open up the database again.... I should be able to just update it as the session is open. However i have tried connecting to the base again.

Comment: The query itself is fine.

Comment: can you post your table schema, please ?

Comment: This code as written could not cause that specific error. Can you post more code for context? most likely, there is a variable being sent to `mysql_query()` which is empty when you expect it to have a value.

Comment: @rcro, +1. This query is an adaptation and might hide the real error

Comment: You should post some more code and db schema.

Comment: Only data that you actively and explicitly store in a session is maintained for that session. You can't store a database connection in session: data in session is stored serialized; a database connection is a resource, and resources can't be serialized... you need to re-establish a database connection for every server request

Comment: ok thanks.... I think that is where I might be wrong... many thanks